# Writing data to a txt file file using java classes

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why my code is not writing the output to the textfile as I expect it to work. My program takes a filename as a command line argument, and prints some text to the file as well as the screen. It is a bit more complicated since it uses classes and objects to demonstrate how objects work. Can anyone help decipher why it is not writing to the file? Here's my code:-

```
public class Mamoonp3test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Create array of 10 guitar (Mamoonp3) objects
        final int NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES = 10;
        Mamoonp3[] objectNames = new Mamoonp3[NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES];

        try 
        {       
            String fileName = new String(args[0]);

            for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES; i++) {
                objectNames[i] = new Mamoonp3(FileName);
                System.out.println("This is guitar number: " + i);
                objectNames[i].tuneGuitar();
                objectNames[i].playGuitar();
                objectNames[i].displayAcronym();
                objectNames[i].stopGuitar();
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("please provide an input file");
            System.out.println("Usage: java Mamoonp3test filename.txt");
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.io.*;

public class Mamoonp3 {

    final int NUMBER_OF_STRINGS = 6;
    char[] stringNames = {'E','A','D','G','B','E'};
    int[] stringNumbers = {6,5,4,3,2,1};
    String[] stringPitch = {"Sixth","Fifth","Fourth","Third","Second","First"};

    boolean isTuned;
    boolean isPlaying;
    String stringAcronym = new String("Even After Dinner Giant Boys Eat");

    //create a PrintWriter for output
    PrintWriter output;

    public Mamoonp3(String fileName) throws Exception{
        isTuned = false;
        isPlaying = false;
        // create target file
        File targetFile = new File(fileName);
        //create a PrintWriter for output
        output = new PrintWriter(targetFile);
    }

    public void tuneGuitar() {
        System.out.println("The guitar is now tuned.");
        for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
            System.out.println(stringNames[i] + " is string number " + stringNumbers[i] + " and ranked " + stringPitch[i] + " in pitch");
            output.print(stringNames[i] + " is string number " + stringNumbers[i] + " and ranked " + stringPitch[i] + " in pitch");
            output.close();
        }
    }

    public void playGuitar() {
        System.out.println("The guitar is now playing.");
        output.print("The guitar is now playing.");
        output.close();
    }

    public void stopGuitar() {
        System.out.println("The guitar is now stoped.");
        output.print("The guitar is now stoped.");
        output.close();
    }

    public void displayAcronym() {
        System.out.println("Always remember your string names!");
        System.out.println("Heres a reminder: " + stringAcronym);
        output.print("Always remember your string names!");
        output.print("Heres a reminder: " + stringAcronym);
        output.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the File of an object that you then do nothing with, that you're not writing with,

```
Mamoonp3 newObject = new Mamoonp3(fileName);
```

... and not setting the File in objects that you try to write with. Check which constructors you are using: every Manoop3 object created in the for loop. To see that this is so, check which constructors you're using

I suggest that you change your approach entirely.

- Get all file input and output **out** of your Mamoonp3 class.
- Instead, that class should concern itself with representing the state of the musical instrument, and nothing else.
- Give the class a decent `toString()` override method.
- I & O should go elsewhere in a separate class of its own.
- Give your I&O class a method that allows you to pass Mamoonp3 objects into it so that they can be written.
- As an aside, you almost never would use `new String(anything)`. Just use `args[0]`.
- **Always** close your PrintWriter when you are done writing. This is likely causing your error.

  ---

**Edit**

Possibly another way to solve this:

- Create a PrintWriter object in the main method.
- Give your Manoop3 class a PrintWriter field and a constructor that takes this PrintWriter and sets its field with it.
- Write with the PrintWriter in Manoop3, but don't close it.
- Then close the PrintWriter in the main method when all Manoop3 objects have completed their use of it.

Comment: @user76020: your latest code won't compile as Filename != fileName

Comment: Is there a quicker way, I have a deadline in 2 hours and I don't have time to redesign the whole thing...any further help is much appreciated...

Comment: @user76020: If you're going to close your output at the end of each method, you need to re-open it at the beginning of each method.

Comment: ooops, sorry that was a typo

Comment: @user76020: you must make sure that the output is closed when you are done with it. Consider either giving the class a `closeOutput()` method that you call at the end that does this, or open and close it in every method.

Comment: @user76020: clarify that last comment please.

Comment: once I closed the file using output.close(), how do I open it?

Comment: The same way you've already opened it. You would create a File and a PrintWriter, and then when done, close the PrintWriter (no need to close the File since you will close the enclosing PrintWriter). You would need to store the File's path in a field if you went this route.

Comment: @user76020: see edit to answer. Probably a better way.

Comment: Thanks man, this was really helpful!! I followed your suggestion of using a separate closeOutput method and it worked like a peach!